# Any app that displays pictures and videos?

Tags: video, vlc, shotwell

I would like an app that shows the pictures and videos.
I use Shotwell (and I've tried a few, like Nomacs and others), but they do not play the videos.
For example, if I click a picture, Shotwell opens up a window with the picture, and I can navigate the images from there (using the arrow keys).
But for videos, it doesn't show a thumbnail, but it does show the video file.
If I double click the video from there, it'll (after a lag) open my videoplayer (VLC), but only that file. To open the next video I must close (or minimize) the last file, then double click the next video.

Answer (score 0):

PCManFM shows thumbnails of video and picture files.

```
sudo apt install pcmanfm
```

Smplayer could be used for recursive video (and audio) files playing or playing videos from a specified folder.

```
sudo apt install smplayer
```

Configure it to add video files from folder as displayed on the picture in
**Options** -> **Playlist** -> **Adding files** section
Checking **Add files in directories recursively** and selecting **Add files from folder:** **Video files**.

[image: sudo apt install smplayer]

But nautilus also shows thumbnails when you toggle its view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
About Nautilus, I see the thumbnails, but I still need to open the files one by one.
I'll try the other suggestions and give feedback later.

Comment: SMPlayer didn't work for what I needed. Is just a player, like VLC.
Thanks anyway.
So for, Gwenview is the closest that I got. The only downside is that Gwenview doesn't show video thumbnails (only pictures).

Answer (score -1):

You can try with [gthumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb):

```
sudo apt install -y gthumb
```

Comment: My gthumb can't play any videos. So maybe gthumb can do it if some other libraries are installed?

Comment: @kanehekili Maybe depends on the version? My gthumb plays videos natively.

Comment: Thanks por the answer.
Installed gthumb. It doesn't recognize almost any files, even the usual (jpeg, mp4, avi...).
It shows the thumbnails for a few videos (but it doesn't play), while not showing for others.
I also tried Gwenview. A little bit heavier, it plays the videos, but it doesn't show thumbnails. I don't know if it's something to do with plugins or libraries

Comment: Sad to hear it, my gthumb is gthumb 3.6.2, and I have no troubles so far, I will see if on other OS behaves differently and let you know.

Comment: Using gthumb 3.9.1. But I haven't all gstreamer plugins installed. (only gst-libav, gst-base). I experienced the same behaviour as the OP

Comment: Yeap, I tried gthumb 3.8 in Ubuntu 20.04 and found the same problems. Now I'm on Debian.

Answer (score -1):

I installed Pix and it solved those issues.
I tried to upgrade to 20.04, but had several problemas, so I'm on Mint now.

Comment: LM is off topic here.

Comment: I know that. Just sharing the solution I've found. If you don't have any contribution, please be nice.